# Who return a value from Foreign key its null and not null

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two databases that i´m using relation between them.
But some rows dont have relationship between them.

For example:

```
Select user.name as name, account.code as code
from user u
JOIN account acc ON u.account_id = acc.id
```

I want to retrieve Null and not null values in code

Comment: An OUTER JOIN will permit NULL

Comment: OUTER JOIN in Mysql?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-simplification.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` like

```
Select user.name as name, account.code as code
from user u
LEFT JOIN account acc ON u.account_id = acc.id
```